# Is there a way to change the title of an article depending on where the aricle is linked?

Tags: nodes

If I have an article linked in different places on my site.  Is there a way to vary the headline to the article based on where it shows up, or how it links?  Some places the liinks are teasers and in others they are not.  Is there a way to change what the headline is?  I already have two different fields prepared for different headlines.

Comment: we'll need to know more detail about where the articles are getting linked.  is this in a view/block?  inside a node?

Comment: The article is in a quicktab block

Comment: Maybe this is a module you can use? `https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle`